# Setting label of context menu dynamically in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

So I have been able to disable a context menu item by using an id: disable and then setting

```
 dijit.byId("disable").set("disabled", true);
```

Is there a way to do this to label?

```
 dijit.byId("labelID").set("label", "hi label");
```

Comment: What dijit widget are you using for your context menu? `dijit.MenuItem`? How are you instantiating your context menu?

Comment: Hi BuffaloBuffalo, Yes, I am using dijit.MenuItem and I am instantiating it programmatically. I was able to disable:true and false by using id but, I do not see a way to .set the label this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dijit.byId("labelID").set("label", "hi label");` does indeed assign the label dynamically. I added it to onRowContextMenu() because it was inside of a grid